# How to extract data from a python list of dictionaries based on multiple key values?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to write a python script that filters a list of dictionaries based on key values.

So i have this list named books.
It contains 5 dictionaries with specific keys: series, reading order and have:

```
books = [

    {'Series': 'A Song of Ice and Fire', 'Reading Order': 'Book 01', 'Have': 'Yes'},
    {'Series': 'Faithful and the Fallen', 'Reading Order': 'Book 02', 'Have': 'Yes'},
    {'Series': 'Warrior Cats', 'Reading Order': 'Book 01', 'Have': 'Yes'},
    {'Series': 'Rome', 'Reading Order': 'Book 01', 'Have': 'No'},
    {'Series': 'Star Wars', 'Reading Order': 'Book 01', 'Have': 'No'}

]
```

I wish to extract from books, the the series values that have the reading order key set to 'Book 01' and the have key to value 'Yes'.
So the expected new list would have only these values:

```
newList = ['A Song of Ice and Fire', 'Warrior Cats']
```

The problem is that i do not know how to get values based on multiple criteria.
what i could do so far is get all the values of the series key:

```
print([i['Series'] for i in allData])
```

But i just cant figure out how to get the series values based on the above mentioned "filters".
Could anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `list comprehension` and check condition like the below:

```
new_books = [dct['Series'] for dct in books if (dct['Reading Order'] == 'Book 01') and (dct['Have'] == 'Yes')]

print(new_books)
```

---

```
['A Song of Ice and Fire', 'Warrior Cats']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add an `if` condition to your list comprehension:

```py
print([i['Series'] for i in books if i['Reading Order'] == 'Book 01' 
                                         and i['Have'] == 'Yes'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
newList = []

for i in books:
   if i["Reading Order"] == 'Book 01' and i["Have"] == "Yes":
       newList.append(i["Series"])
```

This should do the trick, since you want multiple conditions to be true we'll use 'and', therefore our if runs only when both of those conditions are true.

Answer (score 0):

There would be several ways to do this. You could keep it straightforward and loop through the list and check if both conditions are met like so:

```
tempList = []
for book in books:
    if book['Reading Order'] == 'Book 01' and book['Have'] == 'Yes':
        tempList.append(book['Series'])
```

but that will involve using a temporary variable to store the new values in that fit that condition, which may not be ideal.
Another option would be to use the filter function that is built into python. The purpose of this function is to select anything that you does not fit the function that you use. I do not know if you want to keep on a single line, but below contains a solution for that.
For example, you could make the conditional code within the for loop the function to be used - like so:

```
filter(lambda x: (x['Reading Order'] == 'Book 01' and x['Have'] == 'Yes'), books)
```

You would use a lambda function in conjunction so that you can check each item inside of the list like shown above - with the list that you wish to iterate passed in as the second parameter.
This will not return a list however - so you will have to cast to a list but the new list will contain the entire entry of the list like so:

```
>> [{'Series': 'A Song of Ice and Fire', 'Reading Order': 'Book 01', 'Have': 'Yes'}, {'Series': 'Warrior Cats', 'Reading Order': 'Book 01', 'Have': 'Yes'}]
```

One way to only include the series value would like so:

```
list(y['Series'] for y in filter(lambda x: (x['Reading Order'] == 'Book 01' and x['Have'] == 'Yes'), books))
```

by checking the values that were filtered out and only adding the series value.